# Отказ при заливке проекта на репозиторий GitHub

Tags: git, android-studio

При изучении системы контроля версий Git в Android Studio столкнулся с проблемой.
Я руководствовался методом, описанным здесь: http://it-is-not-difficult.blogspot.ru/2014/03/android-studio-git-tutorial.html
При выполнении пятого шага (push) появляется сообщение об ошибке: **Push rejected: master: rejected**. На репозитории ничего не появляется. Тест для проверки версии и работоспособности git-клиента показал, что всё отлично. Не могу понять, что я сделал не так.

Comment: Вероятно, не был настроен ключ для аутентификации на GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему, решив задачу другим способом: создал проект и репозиторий для него прямо из студии, всё коммитится и пушится.